# Using gradleReference feature in cordova plugin.xml

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, cordova-plugins

I'm developing a plugin which needs to pull in some additional dependencies.  Because I expect the end user to work with Android studio, I am using the gradle build by setting ANDROID_BUILD=gradle.

From what I found, including a gradleReference in the plugin.xml seemed the perfect way to do what I needed.  I followed what was done here:

https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/blob/master/cordova/cca-hooks-plugin/plugin.xml

including specifying the higher version of plugman, but it doesn't seem to work.  The included gradle never seems to be run, and I don't see anything added to the project's build.gradle.  I also don't see any errors, however.

I am wondering if this point if the issue is that I am working with released versions of cordova (4.3) and cordova-android (3.7.1) and that possibly I need pre-release versions in order to use gradleReference, but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what I might need.

My plugin.xml includes:

```
<framework src="libs/toolkit_library/toolkit.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
```

and this file exists in the plugin with:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.xxx', name: 'xxx', version: '0.10.0'
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: My question is how to make gradleReference work. I've outlined everything I've tried unsuccessfully.

Comment: I'm having the same issue... any solution or idea yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that in Cordova Android 3.7.1 that I was using, the gradle is included via build.properties, not by modifying the original gradle file (even though there is a marker in the original gradle file that says content will be included there).

This also means that the included gradle only runs via the Cordova build, and not in a standard gradle build, since that does not use build.properties.  In Cordova Android 4.0 this reportedly will no longer be an issue.